# Streaming PC desktop on tv - wireless without internet

Tags: wireless-networking, streaming, tv

Is there a device that allows me to stream desktop on tv via wireless, but without internet? I have Chromecast, but it needs internet connection.

Thank you.

Comment: There are a few devices to broadcast a video and audio signal wirelessly with a "transmitter module" and a "receiver module". Try looking for wireless HDMI

Comment: WiDi, miracast and chromecast should be capable of transferring the screen of the mobile to the TV.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need: [Victake](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA1ZZ4Y13016&ignorebbr=1&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleMKP-PC&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleMKP-PC-_-pla-_-Network%20-%20Wireless%20Adapters-_-9SIA1ZZ4Y13016&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI78vm9OT61QIVCBxpCh33BQgwEAQYAiABEgIHQfD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) ~USD$31

This device is a Wireless (WiFi) HDMI connector that plugs into your TV.  It's Ethernet connectors connects to your Router.  Your PC/Tablet/Phone will connect to the Victake via WiFi and will broadcast your screen on your TV.  This is probably your only choice for a contained device (Meaning it has not internet access).

I am sure you can use it without connecting the Ethernet cable to your router.